# Download data from Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

i try to download data in a class in parse , i have 2 object , they are same trade_id together. But when i download them to a Arraylist it show only 1 ..
Here is my code :

```
final ArrayList<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = new ParseQuery<>("photo");
                query1.whereEqualTo("trade_id",idTrade);
                list = query.find();
                for (ParseObject mPhoto : list) {
                    Photo newPhoto = new Photo();
                    newPhoto.setPhoto((File) mPhoto.get("imageFile"));
                    photos.add(newPhoto);
                }
            } catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            int photosize = photos.size();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+photosize,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Tell me how to fix it? pleae!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `query1.whereMatches` will return all possible matches

```
  ParseQuery<ParseObject> query1 = new ParseQuery<>("photo");
                query1.whereMatches("trade_id",idTrade);
                list = query.find();
```